# I want to implement $or query within the $match aggregation query but shows error unknown operator: $or

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-populate

As I am  working on the nestjs  so the below code is mentioned into my helper.ts file then I am return the query value.

```
const value = searchfields.map((data)=>{

      return {[data]: {$regex: new RegExp(searchString), $options: 'i'}}
    });
    query = {
      $or: value,
    }

return {
    query
  };
```

These is my resolver file

```
const buildQuery = queryBuilder({
      match:{query},
      paginate:{limit,skip},
      populate: [{ model: 'Media', field: 'profileImage', unWind: false }],
      order: { createdAt: -1 },
    });
    });
```

Here is the my query-builder file

```
export const queryBuilder = (payload: IQueryBuilder) => {

let query = [
    {
      $match: payload.match,
    },
  ];
export interface IQueryBuilder {
  populate?: IPopulate[];
  match: any;
  paginate?: IPaginate;
  order?: any;
  total?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: So what query is sent?

Comment: `$or: value` from the helper.ts file  into the resolver file which again return and access into the query-builder file there I got an error unknown operator: $or
Don't know I to solve these issue

Comment: The `queryBuilder` function is missing the return value - can you please update it with the actual implementation?